# Autoscroll in Firefox off-centered

Tags: firefox, mouse

I enabled the autoscroll feature in firefox but it is not working as expected when I hold and drag the middle mouse button.

If I click the middle mouse button and move up or down, the center of the action is correct, i.e. any position above the initial moves the page up, and any position below it moves the page down.

However, if I hold and drag, the center of action is way lower, as shown in this video: https://i.imgur.com/UGDPQNv.mp4

I've had similar quirks in Linux Mint where stuff was rendered on the wrong places but this one seems like a slightly different. I can't tell if it's a problem with Ubuntu or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be fixed in Firefox v82. You can enable the Autoscrolling by going to Preferences and it works as expected.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question?